# Get string from a Observable<string>

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I get one `Observable<string>` called `this.downloadURL` which after calling to my database gets the following value:

[image]

I would like to get its value in the following method:

```
 //Upload a new picture to the database as a profile picture
      uploadBetPicture(event) {
        const id =
          "bet_" +
          Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .substring(2) +
          "_Photo";
        this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(id);
        this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
        this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL();
        //UNTIL HERE I HAVE JUST STORE THE PICTURE AND SET THE OBSERVABLE

        //HERE I GET THE ERROR
        this.photoUrl = this.downloadURL.value;
      }
```

Nevertheless, even when I see the value in my console, I can not access this variable, and I get the following error in `this.photoUrl = this.downloadURL.value`

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Just to add that the storing method works, as I said before, I get the `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `this.task.downloadURL()` is an Observable and your `downloadURL` is wrapped somewhere within that `Observable`, you'll have to `subscribe` to it, to unwrap the value.

Try this:

```
uploadBetPicture(event) {
  const id =
    "bet_" +
    Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substring(2) +
    "_Photo";
  this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(id);
  this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
  this.task.downloadURL()
    .subscribe(value => this.photoUrl = value);
}
```

**NOTE:**

There might be some other keys as well in the value unwrapped from the Observable, so you might want to first log the `value` inside the `subscribe` block to the `console` and then use the appropriate `key` from the `value` object.

Comment: It works, but if I try to access using, for example, console.log(this.photoUrl), from the next line, (not inside the subscribe) I get undefined. Would it be possible to access to this variable outside the subscribe?

Comment: No, it won't be. That's how `async` code works. It would only be available inside the subscribe block. That's the block that gets called when an Observable succeeds. Whatever is written outside it will get called synchronously without waiting for the Observable value to get resolved and unwrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the RxJs documentation, and you'll see that the Angular form of reactive is pretty useful, since you get to do more than just subscribe and wait on the async callback.

For instance, you could query for the first value in the observable:

`YourObservable.first()`

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first

Or the last value:

`YourObservable.last()`

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-last



The full Observable documentation is here:

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html